# Function returning a tuple or None: how to call that function nicely?

Tags: python, return, tuples

Suppose the following:

```
def MyFunc(a):
  if a < 0:
    return None
  return (a+1, a+2, a+3)

v1, v2, v3 = MyFunc()
# Bad ofcourse, if the result was None
```

What is the best way to define a function that returns a tuple and yet can be nicely called. Currently, I could do this:

```
r = MyFunc()
if r:
  v1, v2, v3 = r
else:
  # bad!!
  pass
```

What I don't like about this is that I have to use a single variable and then unpack it.

Another solution is I could have the function return a tuple full of Nones so that the caller can nicely unpack....

Anyone can suggest a better design?

Comment: Which is more pythonic - returning None or returning a tuple of Nones?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about raise an `ArgumentError`? Then you could `try` calling it, and deal with the exception if the argument is wrong.

So, something like:

```
try:
    v1, v2, v3 = MyFunc()
except ArgumentError:
    #deal with it
```

Also, see [katrielalex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448701/function-returning-a-tuple-or-none-how-to-call-that-function-nicely/3448747#3448747) for using a subclass of ArgumentError.

Comment: That is nice, but I am always concerned about the overhead of raising and handling exceptions

Answer (score 10):

This should work nicely:

```
v1, v2, v3 = MyFunc() or (None, None, None)
```

When `MyFunc()` returns a tuple, it will be unpacked, otherwise it will be substituted for a 3-tuple of `None`.

Comment: I don't see how this is better than returning a tuple of `None`s.

Comment: If it is better, it's probably because it doesn't require changing the contents of the function.

Comment: recursive: while the syntax looks nice, it is not that efficient if you need to call MyFunc() many times.

As suggested, better returning the tuple of Nones

Comment: @lallous:  Yes, I agree with that, but the question was explicitly looking for other solutions.

Comment: The problem with this construct is that if I have multiple function calls, I would have to repeat this construct, which is not nice to read more than once....

Answer (score 8):

`recursive` has a truly elegant and Pythonic solution. BUT: why do you want to return `None`? Python has a way of handling errors, and that is by raising an exception:

```
class AIsTooSmallError( ArgumentError ): pass
```

and then

```
raise AIsTooSmallError( "a must be positive." )
```

The reason this is better is that returning a value indicates that you have completed processing and are passing back your answer. This is fine if you have done some processing, but it's silly if you are immediately returning `None`.

Comment: Heh. So you are. But I subclassed `ArgumentError`!

Comment: Yeah, that might be a better option :)

Comment: You could argue that it's not an error condition that causes `None` to be returned. It could just be that the function doesn't have an answer.

Comment: That's true; it's something of a semantic argument. It'll depend on the actual content of the code.

Comment: Now that deserves another question. I haven't fully researched yet but:
What is the cost of Python exceptions?

Or rephrased differently, what is better:
- returning (None, None, None)
or
- throwing an exception

?

Comment: It depends. Python exceptions aren't *very* efficient, but you're not using them in a tight loop so that's OK.

Answer (score 4):

> Another solution is I could have the function return a tuple full of Nones so that the caller can nicely unpack....

What's wrong with that?  Consistency is a good thing.

Comment: I agree. In fact that way it maintains the return signature of function. +1

Comment: Maintaining return signatures is soooo static ;)

Comment: @Skilldrick: In my experience, a consistent return signature promotes dynamism by allowing one to remain ignorant of silly details and exceptions.  But I'm just lazy.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the `v1, v2, v3` objects to exist and be set to a default value in the case of an error, return the default values yourself. This will make the calling code simpler by not relying on the caller to set them manually:

```
def MyFunc(a):
    if a < 0:
        # can't use a negative value; just return some defaults
        return (None, None, None)
    return (a+1, a+2, a+3)
```

On the other hand, if a default return is not appropriate and a negative argument is considered a serious error, raise an exception:

```
def MyFunc(a):
    if a < 0:
        # sorry, negative values are unacceptable
        raise ValueError('cannot accept a negative value')
    return (a+1, a+2, a+3)
```

On the *third* hard, returning `None` may be preferable sometimes when returning a single object, as is the case with the `search()` and `match()` functions of the `re` module. It somehow stands between the first two cases, because matching failure is an expected outcome, while a default return object wouldn't be very useful anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the previous answer. You could return either an object instance or None

```
def MyFunc(a):
    class MyFuncClass(object):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    if a < 0:
        return None
    return MyFuncClass(one=a+1, two=a+2, three=a+3)

o = MyFunc(1)
if o is not None:
    print o.one, o.two, o.three
```